# Web Audio frequency limitation?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, fft, web-audio-api

My goal is to generate an audio at a certain frequency and then check at what frequency it is using the result of FFT.

```
function speak() {
  gb.src = gb.ctx.createOscillator();
  gb.src.connect(gb.ctx.destination);
  gb.src.start(gb.ctx.currentTime);
  gb.src.frequency.value = 1000;
}

function listen() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia
            || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio : true,
        video : false
    }, function(stream) {
        gb.stream = stream;
        var input = gb.ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        gb.analyser = gb.ctx.createAnalyser();
        gb.analyser.fftSize = gb.FFT_SIZE;
        input.connect(gb.analyser);

        gb.freqs = new Uint8Array(gb.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        setInterval(detect, gb.BIT_RATE / 2);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('The following gUM error occured: ' + err);
    });
}
```

See working example at http://codepen.io/Ovilia/full/hFtrA/ . You may need to put your microphone near the speaker to see the effect.

The problem is, when the frequency is somewhere larger than 15000 (e.g. 16000), there seems not to be any response at high frequency area any more.

**Is there any limit of frequency with Web Audio, or is it the limit of my device?**

**What is the unit of each element when I get from `getByteFrequencyData`?**

Comment: The frequency response of most consumer grade microphones and speakers typically starts to fall off at 15 kHz and above.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there any limit of frequency with Web Audio, or is it the limit of my device?

I don't think the WebAudio framework itself limits this. Like the other answers have mentioned here. The limit is probably from microphone's and loudspeaker's physical limits.

I tried to use the my current bookshelf loudspeaker (Kurzweil KS40A) I have along with a decent microphone (Zoom H4). The microphone was about 1 cm from the tweeter.

[image: Analyzer data at 5kHz]
[image: Analyzer data at 15kHz]
[image: Analyzer data at 17kHz]
[image: Analyzer data at 19kHz]

As you see, with these loudspeakers and microphones aren't able to effeciently generate/capture sounds at those frequencies.

This is more obvious when you look at the [Zoom H4's frequency response](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h4/mic.html). Unfortunately I couldn't find a frequency respose for the KS40a.

You can also do something similar using non browser tools to check if you see similar results.

#### What is the unit of each element when I get from getByteFrequencyData?

The unit of each element from getByteFrequencyData is a normalized magnitude data of from the FFT scaled to fit the dBFS range of the `maxDecibles` and `minDecibles` attributes on the `AnalyserNode`. So a byte value 0 would imply `minDecibles` (default is -100dBFS) or lower and a byte value of 255 would imply `maxDecibles` (default is -30dBFS) or higher.

Comment: I tried with Audacity and with freq at 17000Hz, which the speaker is capable to generate since I can hear it, but the FFT result is still near 0. So would it be possible to amplify the audio at certain frequency to make the data from analyser larger?

Comment: Yup. So it might be the microphone which can't pick up 17000Hz. Amplification will certainly help. Even our ears here the more extreme (low or high) frequencies better at higher loudness levels. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%E2%80%93Munson_curves

Answer (score 2):

Lookup the concept of Nyquist Frequency - the default sampling rate of web audio is 44.1kHz - this means the theoretical maximum frequency would be 22050 hertz given perfect hardware such as microphone and analog-to-digital converter inside your computer.  @Ovilia on that same computer using same microphone record the same input sound and then examine the audio file using a utility like Audacity where you can view the output of its FFT analysis - in Audacity when you open an audio file go to menu Analyze -> Plot Spectrum ... also to see a very nice FFT view click the down arror near left side of waveform view subwindow and pick Spectrogram - another excellent FFT capable audio tool is called Sonic Visualizer - are you now seeing power at frequencies you are not seeing  using FFT within web audio ?

Comment: True - but in theory this still allows for frequencies in the range 15 - 20 kHz, which is where the OP is having problems. It's more likely to be due to the limitations of the transducers at higher frequencies.

Comment: I think it unlikely, if that were the case the sample rate it would be 30 Khz to reproduce the limitation from the @Ovilia Question...

Comment: The Nyquist frequency of half the sample rate is only valid for infinite length signals and infinitely long FFTs, or for just the right phase.  For shorter FFTs, the max frequency for an arbitrary unknown phase input is lower than Fs/2.

Comment: Web Audio uses whatever the hardware's sampling rate is - frequently 44.1kHz, but not always.

Comment: I tried to analysis the FFT result from audacity and the value when frequency is larger than 15000Hz is even weaker than generated from Web Audio. Does this mean that it's not feasible to use such high freq to send the message?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most microphones just works well in the voice range frequency, something around [80 Hz to 1100 Hz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_range)

So probably do you have a hardware limit problem, try check with manufacturer or manual the frequency input response from your device !

Comment: You're looking at speech - the frequency response for consumer grade microphones and speakers is typically of the order of 50 Hz - 15 kHz which is good enough for medium fidelity speech and music.

Comment: Thaks @PaulR make sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an anti-alias low pass filter (between the microphone and the ADC) which has a cut-off below Fs/2 in order to make sure everything is rolled off by that frequency (given a finite filter transition width).

There may also be nulls in the room's acoustics.  At frequencies above 2 Khz, it might be only inches from a peak to a null location for the microphone placement.